# How to get the predefined Tagged Value Type RefGuid type or stereotype of EA through Addin

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA the RefGuid type of Tagged Value has format Values=Type1,Type2;
Stereotypes=Stereotype1.Using addin how to get the Values and Stereotypes values.i.e Type1,Type2 and Stereotype1 values.

Answer (score 2):

See `EA.Repository.PropertyTypes` 
That contains a list of [EA.Property](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/propertytype.html) which represent the tagged value types defined in the model.

It will however not contain the ones defined in MDG technologies.